# concatenate all strings of one variable in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, string-concatenation

I have a dataframe with a variable called var1 and var2. There are 5 observations, as follows:

var1   var2

```
1  hello there
2  my name is
3  john and 
4  i am 30 years 
5  old
```

is there a way to concatenate each observation string in var2 into one string? for example, create a string that concatenates the observations within a var: "hello there my name is john and i am 30 years old"

I looked everywhere online for a way to turn each observation for a particular var into one string, but could not find an example.

Comment: Just try searching for it first, please.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `join`:

```
s = ' '.join(df['var2'])
print (s)
hello there my name is john and i am 30 years old
```

Comment: Damn, you're fast! :)

Comment: @user5173426 indeed, typing one liners to duplicate questions is easy.